# How is this implementation of fabs() working?

Tags: c, floating-point

The algorithm for finding the absolute value of a floating point number over [here](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Absolute%20Value%20of%20a%20Float).
How does this work?

```
//find absolute value
double x;
*(((int *) &x) + 1) &= 0x7fffffff;
```

**I don't understand why the offset of 1 was necessary**. It says:

> the IA32 64-bit sign bit is 0x80000000 at an int address offset of +1.

Can someone break this down and explain?

Comment: "Can someone break this down and explain?" - perhaps you could attempt an explanation?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Perhaps you could be a bit less judgemental. OP's question was clearly worded, and even explained the particular point of confusion: the offset 1.

Comment: @R: I asked a polite and reasonable question. What's your beef?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is technically invalid C as it breaks strict aliasing rules.  However, if you tell your compiler not to abuse the aliasing rules and you're guaranteed that `double`s and `int`s are laid out in memory as they are on an x86:

`(int *)&x` is a pointer to `x`.  Adding 1 moves the pointer forward by 4 bytes.  Dereferencing it gives you the 4th through 7th bytes of the `double`.  You mask off the high bit of this because that is the last byte of the `double`.

Incidentally, you can stop this from being an aliasing violation by using a `char *` and adding 7 instead of 1.  It's still horribly nonportable.

Comment: Nice answer. You seem familiar.

Comment: And with your modification to use `char` I would say it's only *mildly* non-portable not horribly so. Really the only non-portable aspect is the endianness assumption. Assuming that `double` is IEEE double-precision stored in IEEE format is a fairly reasonable assumption.

Comment: Another fun, possibly more "portable", way to do it is using unions to convert back and forth from a `uint64_t` view of the representation, and taking `R2D(D2R(x)&~D2R(-0.0))`. where `R2D` and `D2R` convert the representation to a `double` and back. Note that this completely avoids the endianness issue and even allows for the bytes (or even bits) of the IEEE representation to be permuted in an arbitrary manner not matching any classic "endianness".

Answer (score 8):

A `double` is 8 bytes wide and has the following format:

[image]

The code you show assumes that `int` is 4 bytes wide, and that both `int` and `double` are [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (meaning bits 0-7 are stored in byte 0, bits 8-15 in byte 1 and so on).

If `x` is a pointer to `double`:

```
*(((int *) &x) + 0) addresses bits 0 through 31;
*(((int *) &x) + 1) addresses bits 32 through 63.
```

Thus, `*(((int *) &x) + 1) &= 0x7fffffff` sets bit 63 to zero, changing `x` to its absolute value.

Comment: @tmyklebu And that, my friends, is how the endian wars started. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is highly platform dependent.

Anyway, you have a double where the highest bit is the sign bit.

If your double has 8 byte and your int has 4 byte, and you are on a LE system, the highest bit is the highest bit of the last byte, or of the second integer.

So you take the second integer (you could write as well `((int *)&x)[1] &= 0x7fffffff`) and clear its highest bit.